# some files are not found when I try to run my android project

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I use android studio 1.5 and I have this error when I start my project. I would precised that it was walking well and I don't know what change caused this. please if anyone has any idea 's will be welcome

```
Error:java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\kef\AndroidStudioProjects\UDMAC\.gradle\2.8\taskArtifacts\cache.properties (Le fichier spécifié est introuvable)
```

> C:\Users\kef\AndroidStudioProjects\UDMAC.gradle\2.8\taskArtifacts\cache.properties (Le fichier spécifié est introuvable)

Comment: Try reimporting your project since it does seem to be a gradle issue

Comment: The project was created on this machine is not a project import

Comment: have you tried that ? you can import existing projects

Comment: I have try but I got the same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would update your android studio to the latest version from [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html). Then copy your files to the new project folder location.

Comment: not is there a way to solve this problem without changing the android studio version ?

Comment: Have you tried restarting the system? You could also try and restore your computer to an earlier version if it has worked in the past.

Comment: I have update android studio has you have said and it work thx